# What is the correct way to support `__shfl()` and `__shfl_sync()` instructions?

Tags: cuda, ptx, ptxas

From my understanding, CUDA 10.1 removed the `shfl` instructions:

> PTX ISA version 6.4 removes the following features:
>
> Support for `shfl` and vote instructions without the `.sync` qualifier has been removed for .targetsm_70 and higher. This support was deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 as documented in PTX ISA version 6.2.

What is the correct way to support `shfl` future and past CUDA versions?

My current methods (shared below) result in the error using CUDA 10.1:

```
ptxas ... line 466727; error   : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is not supported on .target sm_70 and higher from PTX ISA version 6.4
```

```
template <typename T>
__device__ static __forceinline__
T _shfl_up(T var, unsigned int delta, int width=WARPSIZE, unsigned mask=MEMBERMASK)
{
#if (__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ >= 9)
  var = __shfl_up_sync(mask, var, delta, width);
#else
  var = __shfl_up(var, delta, width);
#endif
  return var;
}
```

Also, I would like to add that one of the dependencies of my project is [CUB](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub) and I believe they utilize the same method to split up `_sync()` and older `shfl` instructions. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing the right thing, turns out another dependency didn't have support for `sync`, created a pull request for it: https://github.com/moderngpu/moderngpu/pull/32

```
template <typename T>
__device__ static __forceinline__
T _shfl_up(T var, unsigned int delta, int width=WARPSIZE, unsigned mask=MEMBERMASK)
{
#if ( __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 300)
#if (__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ >= 9)
  var = __shfl_up_sync(mask, var, delta, width);
#else
  var = __shfl_up(var, delta, width);
#endif
#endif
  return var;
}
```